# Centre an image on top of a CSS shape?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image on to a Hexagon made using CSS.

The code I currently have is:

```css
.img-social {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
   
}

.hexagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 35px; 
    height: 20.21px;
    background-color: #525555;
    margin: 10.10px 0;
}
  
.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 17.5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17.5px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 10.10px solid #525555;
}

.hexagon:after {
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 10.10px solid #525555;
}
```

```html
<li class="img-social-container">
     <div class="hexagon"></div>
     <a><img class="img-social" src="icons/logo-github.png" alt="github"></a>
</li>
```

I also want the image to be ontop of the hexagon which is another problem I am having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move it? I'm somewhat sure it's not the best solution, but still.

```
.img-social {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 32.5px;
        left: 5px;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this works but the only problem is that the background of my logo is transparent and adopts the background of the page and not the hexagon. so is there away for the background to be the same colour as the hexagon without just changing its background colour?

Comment: I figured it out, i can just use the background colour property. Thank you